# How to send an imgur API request from an async task

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

Please as I'm a networking newbie I would love if you could dumb everything down to me.
So I am developing an android app. I have worked with APIs before, but the imgur's one is really difficult to understand. For example I am used to the kind of APIs where I paste an address into the browser and I can see the json.
Then I can save that json as a string in Java and parse it with JSONObject.
Imgur instead uses this thing called OAuth that is unlike API keys. For example if I paste this into the browser bar
https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/album/bRpHL
I get an error. The docs say that I have to

```
send an authorization header with your client_id in your requests
```

but there is no ?api_key= like parameter. there are examples with cURL which I don't know what it is or I could implement it in an AsyncTask.
So in conclusion: I just want to get data about images in an imgur album. I have a client_id but no idea how to get the result json. Many thanks.
API docs: http://api.imgur.com/